Strong Convergence of the Product of Sequences in L2 with Uniform Boundedness
Let $f_n$ and $g_n$ be sequences in $L^2(\Omega)$ such that $f_n \to f$ strongly in $L^2(\Omega)$ and $g_n \to g$ strongly in $L^2(\Omega)$. Additionally, suppose $\|f_n\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \leq C$ for some constant $C > 0$. My question is whether we can prove that $f_n g_n \to fg$ strongly in $L^2(\Omega)$.
I can prove using the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem that if $g_n \to g$ almost everywhere in $\Omega$, then the conclusion holds. However, for the specific case where $f_n$ and $g_n$ are converging strongly in $L^2(\Omega)$ and $f_n$ is uniformly bounded in $L^\infty(\Omega)$, I have the following approach:
We can extract subsequences $(f_{n_k})$ and $(g_{n_k})$ such that $f_{n_k} \to f$ and $g_{n_k} \to g$ almost everywhere in $\Omega$. By using Theorem 2.3 from Antonio Ambrosetti and Giovanni Prodi's book A Primer of Nonlinear Analysis (Cambridge University Press, 1995), we know that $|g_{n_k}|$ is bounded almost everywhere by some function $\tilde{g} \in L^2(\Omega)$. Moreover, $f_{n_k} g_{n_k} \to fg$ almost everywhere in $\Omega$.
Moreover, since $|f_{n_k} g_{n_k}| \leq C \tilde{g}$, we can apply the $L^2$ Dominated Convergence Theorem to deduce that $f_{n_k} g_{n_k} \to fg$ strongly in $L^2(\Omega)$.
However, my concern is how to extend this result to the whole sequence ${f_n}$ and ${g_n}$, not just the subsequences. I have seen in previous discussions that a sub-subsequence argument can be used, but it is not entirely clear to me how to apply it in this context. Could you please clarify how to prove that the entire sequence $f_n g_n$ converges strongly to $fg$ in $L^2(\Omega)$?

Prove it by contradiction.

You might look for this argument. However, if I am not missing something, then Hölder inequality should be enough, even if there is no uniform $L^\infty$-bound on $f_n$.

@HyperbolicPDEfriend: The Hölder inequality would give you convergence in $L^1$, not $L^2$.

I see, how was I missing this... Thanks

This is the so-called "double subsequence trick", or in this case, really a triple subsequence.  I like to think of it as follows.
Suppose to the contrary that $f_n g_n$ does not converge in $L^2$ to $fg$.  Then there exists a subsequence $f_{n_k} g_{n_k}$ and an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\|f_{n_k} g_{n_k} - fg \|_{L^2} > \epsilon$ for all $k$.  (This comes from simply negating the definition of sequence convergence in a metric space.)
Now since $f_{n_k} \to f$ in $L^2$, we have a subsequence $f_{n_{k_j}}$ such that $f_{n_{k_j}} \to f$ almost everywhere.  For these same indices, we still have $g_{n_{k_j}} \to g$ in $L^2$, so can find a further subsequence $g_{n_{k_{j_i}}} \to g$ almost everywhere.  Since $f_{n_{k_{j_i}}}$ is a subsequence of an a.e.-convergent sequence, it converges a.e. to $f$ as well.
Now we have $f_{n_{k_{j_i}}} g_{n_{k_{j_i}}} \to fg$ almost everywhere and satisfying the dominated convergence theorem hypotheses, so $f_{n_{k_{j_i}}} g_{n_{k_{j_i}}} \to fg$ in $L^2$.
On the other hand, $f_{n_{k_{j_i}}} g_{n_{k_{j_i}}}$ is a subsequence of the original $f_{n_k} g_{n_k}$, so it still satisfies $\|f_{n_{k_{j_i}}} g_{n_{k_{j_i}}} - fg\|_{L^2} > \epsilon$ for all $i$.  This is in contradiction with our showing that $f_{n_{k_{j_i}}} g_{n_{k_{j_i}}} \to fg$ in $L^2$.
